# on_member_update doesn't do anything

Tags: python, discord.py

Doesn't give me an error. I can't paste the whole code since it's too long, so I'll try to paste what I think is causing the problem.

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["#","a#"], intents = intents)

lastseen_onehour = []
lastseen_sixhours = []
lastseen_twentyfourhours = []
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    cycle_onehour = 60*1
    cycle_sixhours = 60*300
    cycle_twentyfourhours = 60*1380
    if after.status == "offline":
        lastseen_onehour.append(after)
        await asyncio.sleep(cycle_onehour)
        lastseen_onehour.remove(after)
        lastseen_sixhours.append(after)
        await asyncio.sleep(cycle_sixhours)
        lastseen_sixhours.remove(after)
        lastseen_twentyfourhours.append(after)
        await asyncio.sleep(cycle_twentyfourhours)
        lastseen_twentyfourhours.remove(after)
```

What I'm trying to do is keep record of how long it's been since a user went offline. A "last seen at" function basically. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have the presences intent?

Comment: @Wasi Master yep, edited the code to include that too

Comment: you don't have the presences intent. the members intent is not the same as the presences intent

Comment: @Wasi Master How do I add them to my code? I looked it up and couldn't find anything

Comment: just wrote an answer, check it out.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is just the default intents ([everything except `presences` and `members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#:%7E:text=except%20presences%20and%20members.)). and you enabled the members intent, you also need the presences one,

so one way would be to add `intents.presences = True` after the `intents.members = True` line. but since you are using all intents you can just do

```py
intents = discord.Intents.all()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=["#","a#"], intents = intents)
```

you can also omit the variable in this case.

also make sure the presences intent is enabled in the dev portal too: [image: example]

Comment: Also, I just noticed your prefix order, see the note in [the docs for Bot.command_prefix](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.command_prefix) to know why this is bad

Comment: It still doesn't work. Changed my status from dnd to offline and it still didn't trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! All I did was replace

```
if after.status == "offline":
```

with

```
if str(after.status) == "offline":
```

Comment: I didn't even notice that, but yeah the [presences intent is required to access member status](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/master/api.html?highlight=Member.status#discord.Intents.presences)